# NGINX http proxy_pass over SSL throws error 502

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm trying to set up SSL on my nginx server, it works on the plain site wich is just the nginx welcome default page, but when I try any of the configured proxy_pass locations I get a cloudflare 526 Invalid SSL certificate error wich rapidly flicks to a 502 bad gateway. The certificate I'm using is self signed and cloudflare SSL is set to full (not strict).

This is the error I get on my logs:

```
2017/11/28 22:59:10 [error] 11457#11457: *2 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:  141.101.104.32, server: web1.olympiccode.net, request: "GET /r/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2000/r/", host: "web1.olympiccode.net", referrer: "https://web1.olympiccode.net/r"
```

This is my config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    send_timeout 1800;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  6500;

    ssl_certificate      server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  server.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols        SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  web1.olympiccode.net;
    return 200 "hi";
}
# HTTPS server

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  web1.olympiccode.net;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    ssl on;
    location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /r/ {
      auth_basic "RethinkDB - Web Panel";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.rethinkdb.pass;
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:2000;
      proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
      proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
      proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
      proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
      proxy_read_timeout 1800;
      proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    }
    location /status/ {
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:19999;
      proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
      proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
      proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
      proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
      proxy_read_timeout 1800;
      proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    }
}
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error was caused by a cloudflare misconfiguration in the SSL settings.

I have two different setups, a normal web hosting that I use for my website and a VPS wich I use for databases and other things, due to that and the web host having SSL certificates I had cloudflare SSL set to "Full (Strict)" and a page rule setting "web1.olympiccode.net" to only "Full", however, the cloudflare page rules work on URLs and not hosts, so I had to change it to "web1.olympiccode.net/*" after that it worked fine.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to clarify a bit more about what the misconfiguration was, or at least how it was found? It would probably be helpful to other people who may have the same problem.